# Why a merged namespace is created instead of a submodule?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I added my module for creating blanks migration, views, controllers, etc.;

```
private function createModel()
{
    $model = Str::singular(Str::studly(class_basename($this->argument('name'))));

    $this->call('make:model',[
        'name' => "App\\Modules\\".trim($this->argument('name'))."\\Models\\".$model
    ]);

}
```

[image: my result]

[image: What I expect :]

After running the

> php artisan make:module Admin\Users --model --controller

command in the console, I get the wrong structure (pic1)

Comment: I have ubuntu20 + php7.4 installed